# haproxy error on restarting

Tags: linux, centos, cloud, haproxy

HAProxy error on restarting. This is the error i have:

```
# systemctl status haproxy

● haproxy.service - SYSV: HA-Proxy is a TCP/HTTP reverse proxy which is particularly suited for high availability environments.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-11-03 03:34:04 EDT; 16s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6170 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 03 03:34:04 server systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: HA-Proxy is a TCP/HTTP reverse proxy which is particularly suited for high availability environments....
Nov 03 03:34:04 server haproxy[6170]: /etc/rc.d/init.d/haproxy: line 26: [: =: unary operator expected
Nov 03 03:34:04 server haproxy[6170]: Starting haproxy: [WARNING] 306/033404 (6178) : config : frontend 'GLOBAL' has no 'bind' directive. Please declare it... intended.
Nov 03 03:34:04 server haproxy[6170]: [ALERT] 306/033404 (6178) : Starting frontend http_front: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
Nov 03 03:34:04 server haproxy[6170]: [FAILED]
Nov 03 03:34:04 server systemd[1]: haproxy.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 03 03:34:04 server systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: HA-Proxy is a TCP/HTTP reverse proxy which is particularly suited for high availability environments..
Nov 03 03:34:04 server systemd[1]: Unit haproxy.service entered failed state.
Nov 03 03:34:04 server systemd[1]: haproxy.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

My configuration file:

[haproxy.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPDho.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using systemd, you should use systemd unit file instead of the init.d script.

I don't know how you installed haproxy, you can find `haproxy.service` in haproxy source directory(`contrib/systemd`), copy it to systemd folder and use it.

```
cp contrib/systemd_haproxy.service /lib/systemd/system/
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable haproxy
systemctl start haproxy
systemctl status haproxy
```